# how to add environment variables in VS2010 using .bat file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, batch-file, environment-variables, pre-build-event

I have a batch file with this code:

```
@echo off
set VAR=7
echo the version is %VAR%
```

I want to add this .bat file to my visual studio project, using pre-build event. 
I wrote in the pre build event the path to the batch file, but then when I enter the : Resources ->PreProcessor definitions - I can't see the VAR 
How can I add it?
any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: This doesn't work, unless you run everything from the batch file. When  settings environment variables, this only affects the local process and doesn't change the global settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your BAT script to be something like

```
echo #define VER 7 > version.h
```

and then have your code use

```
#include "version.h"
```

Comment: Im sorry for the question - but it this the syntax for creating the .h file ? i should use : "#define ver 7 > version.h ? " or this sign ">" is just u showing me the direction?

Comment: The ">" says to send the output of echo to a file.